# Bijective Mapping Between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I am looking to show that these two sets have the same cardinality. I know that since $\mathbb{R}$ is infinite, $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ must also be infinite as we have just taken a finite number of elements out (really just the one). Nevertheless, I want to formalize this by finding a bijective mapping between the two and just can't seem to figure out what it would be. Are there any simple examples?

Comment: Just a remark: If you have two infinite sets, there isn't necessarily a bijection between them (e.g. between a set and its powerset).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply define $f(x) = \begin{cases}x + 1, \text{if } x \in \Bbb N;\\x, \text{else.}\end{cases}$, where $\Bbb N = \{0, 1, 2, \dots\}$ is the set of non-negative integers.

Then $f$ is a bijection from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R\backslash \{0\}$.

Comment: No, it’s a bijection from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R\setminus\color{red}{\{}0\color{red}{\}}$; the curly braces are required.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Alright... I just followed the notation of the original post.

Comment: Sorry I had the braces I just didn't realize mathjax required the backslash before

Comment: @joseph: You’re not the first to run into that problem, believe me!

Comment: @PeterForeman: It’s clear from context (and in my opinion by far the preferable and more natural usage), but it is probably safer to be explicit.

Comment: What's the intuition used for creating this mapping? I understand it so clearly now that I see it, however, I am unsure if I would've created this on my own just tinkering with different functions.

Comment: It is essentially a bijection from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N \backslash \{0\}$, and everything outside $\Bbb N$ just remains untouched. The bijection from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N \backslash \{0\}$ can be visualized as "moving one step to the right".

Answer (score 1):

WhatsUp solution sends $0$ to $1$, then $1$ is moved to $2$ and so on $0\to 1\to 2\to 3\to\cdots$ up to infinity.

Another common trick usually used with $[0,1]\mapsto(0,1]$ is to move $0\to \frac 12\to\frac 14\to\frac 18\to\cdots$ down to zero in the bounded case. Of course you can use it also to map $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

Note: *basically you can remove a single point $c_0$ by mapping it to another number $c_1$, then send $c_1$ to yet another $c_2$ and so on, while pushing the collinding numbers $c_n$ away. Thus sequences like $c_n=n$ or $c_n=p^{-n}$ are convenient to realize simple bijections.*